# How to check cron syntax by script like "crontab -e" does?

Tags: linux, syntax, cron

Let's say I write cron files via script and modify them direct under
`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`. When using the command `crontab -e` crontab checks the syntax when I exit the editor. Is there any way to do the same check via script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crontab with -e option does open your default editor with the current cron file and installs it after exiting.

First of all, save your actual cron file to be sure of not losing or breaking anything.

```
crontab -l > backup.cron
```

You can directly install a file that you have cooked:

```
crontab yourFile.text
```

Or use a pipe in a script:

```
#/bin/bash
Variable="your scheduled tasks"
echo $Variable | crontab
```

You will get the error messages in the case of bad formatting.

More info: [man crontab](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/crontab/)

Comment: Keep in mind that this will delete any previous crontab there was before, check it with `crontab -l` before

Comment: @golimar yes, all protection is good when you touch this kind of configuration files. I update my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`chkcrontab`](https://pypi.org/project/chkcrontab/):

```sh
pip3 install chkcrontab
```

```sh
chkcrontab /etc/cron.d/power-schedule
Checking correctness of /etc/cron.d/power-schedule
E: 15: 0 12 * foo * * root echo hi
e:     FIELD_VALUE_ERROR: foo is not valid for field "month" (foo)
e:     INVALID_USER: Invalid username "*"
E: There were 2 errors and 0 warnings.
```

Or try a shell script `48-verifycron` from [Wicked Cool Shell Scripts, 2nd Edition](https://nostarch.com/wcss2/), but it's not as good.

Comment: i started managing my cron-jobs with git and "chkcrontab" helps me inside my bash script to check if files are valid before pushing them into crontab, it works perfectly!